# Some Virtual Machines can't co-exist with WSL

Tags: virtualization, vmware, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Some of my virtual machines in VMWare (Windows guests) only work when 'Virtual machine platform' is disabled in 'Optional windows features'

This in turn breaks WSL

Anyone else encountered this.

```
This error on windows guests I have with it enabled is doesn't supported nested VMs (Module HV failed to start)
```

something hypervisor related.

Clearly not used on my other VMs

Is there no way around this.

I have all virtualisation features on in BIOS

I am running the current version of VMWare workstation Pro (16.2.3 build-19376536 as of 02/04/2022)

Comment: VMware Player/Workstation has improved compatibility with the Windows Hypervisor Platform with each version. Is your VMware software up to date? // Do you actually need nested virtualization in your VMs?

Comment: VMware uptodate. But I have an idea to disable hypervisor in the vm via bcdedit see if that helps

Comment: @MANICX100 I believe that's going to disable WSL2

Comment: “Anyone else encountered this.” - What version of VMWare are you using. Be as specific as possible. Only the supported and current versions of VMWare Hypervisor products support VMP.

Comment: The current version of VMWare Workstation supports Hyper-V being enabled. This configuration requires a supported version of Windows. Check the VMWare website for which versions are supported

Comment: This is odd then as I am running the current version of VMWare workstation Pro (16.2.3 build-19376536 as of 02/04/2022)

Comment: You have to be running Windows 10 21H2 or Windows 11 21H2 as the host. Although it's worth pointing out that performance with Hyper-V installed is effected, so it's best to select a single hypervisor, and use that instead. VMWare will work with only `Virtual Machine Platform` being enabled instead of `Virtual Machine Platform` and `Hyper-V` both being installed.

Comment: This issue might then be because I am running the win11 beta build 22H2 22581.200

Comment: Still an issue on Windows 10 21H2 19044.1889, VMWare 16.2.4. `Virtual Machine Platform` prevents VMWare from working. Hyper-V is disabled.

Comment: I've had multiple crashes (blue screens) when running Windows 11 Pro / WSL2 and VMWare Workstation together. I don't have the Pro version of VMWare. When I turn of the right BIOS feature to support hypervisors then the crashes go away :| Probably have to reinstall everything... Uninstalling VMWare didn't resolve the issue. Was running fine beforehand (do have additional mem installed, but running memtest doesn't show any problems)

Answer (score 5):

When WSL2 is enabled, the "Virtual Machine Platform" feature is turned on in Windows.  This is a subset of Hyper-V functionality, which enables a type 1 hypervisor.  Once this is enabled, *Windows itself* is actually running inside the hypervisor.

As a result, VMWare is a "nested" (type 2) hypervisor attempting to run inside the VMP type 1 hypervisor.

In order for this to work, you'll need all of the components involved to support the Nested Virtualization feature.

This apparently requires:

- [Workstation 15.5.5 Pro: Windows](https://blogs.vmware.com/workstation/2020/05/vmware-workstation-now-supports-hyper-v-mode.html)
- For Intel, a recent Windows 10 release or Windows 11.
- For AMD processors, Windows 11 is required

Alternatively, you should still be able to run WSL1 at the same time as VMWare, since WSL1 does not use virtualization.

Comment: Nested virtualization does not actually  require 21H2, it’s more like 20H2, since VMP support was added in a minor update to VMWare Workstation 15 back in late 2019 early 2020. However, 1909 and 20H1 are not supported, so your probably should just install 21H2

Comment: @Ramhound That's a good point - For Intel at least, right?  I'm on AMD, and I think nested virtualization for AMD wasn't added until 21H2, right?

Comment: I don’t believe that’s accurate

Comment: @Ramhound It seems we're both wrong in this case.  Nested virtualization support for AMD processors was in Insider builds as early as 2020, but the feature [wasn't released on Windows 10](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/ol3smt/comment/h5dhafb/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3).  It requires Windows 11.  I know , I know - Reddit isn't the best "source", but all I can find is a lot of announcements about AMD nested-virt when it came to Insider, but no report of it ever being in any released Windows version.

Comment: If it was in a pre-Windows 11 Windows 10 Insider Previews build I can understand the lack of information.  Those Builds before Windows 11 was announcement are a black hole of information, there were many features that were supposed to come to Windows 10 21H2 that never happened due to the divergence of Windows 11. I expect some time in the future we might see some minor changes and/or features  from Windows 11 come to Windows 10 provided Windows 10 22H2 doesn’t happen (yeah I know that doesn’t make sense either but I have my reasons) of course I put $2,000 on a bet on Windows on Apple M1. Oops

Comment: This is odd then as I am running the current version of VMWare workstation Pro (16.2.3 build-19376536 as of 02/04/2022)

Comment: @MANICX100 Still noodling on this, but for now I don't have any further suggestions for you, unfortunately. :-/.  Let us know if you figure it out in the meantime.

Comment: Still an issue on Windows 10 21H2 19044.1889, VMWare 16.2.4. Virtual Machine Platform prevents VMWare from working. Hyper-V is disabled.